# Upgrade to 200 amp by adding another main panel?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, air-conditioning

I want to install central air conditioning in my home but my current service is 100 amps.

If I were to upgrade to 200 amps service, could the breakers be configured where I have two 100 amp main breakers, one will be the already existing breaker box servicing the house as usual, and the other would be just for the central air conditioning.

Is this possible to configure like this?

Comment: And the fact that the other one was migrated here after being cross-posted to Electronics is why you don't cross post.

Comment: Yeah, please don’t cross-post.  All the copies end up migrated to the correct forum, where they are dupes of each other, scattering answers all over the place and wasting answerer’s time.

Comment: Check the time, I posted it here when they said to, then they moved it afterwards, calm down.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes, the 2020 code now requires the mains to be outside so updating to a dual main and feeding each of your panels makes sense. Your existing main will become a sub so neutrals will need to be isolated in the panel.
This kind of update is one of the easier ones and helps to move mains out to the service.